# Replace a pattern in all lines but only before another pattern

Tags: vim

I have files like this:

```
something something other text MARKER bla bla something
something else something MARKER foo bar etc pp something
```

I want to replace `something` with `another thing`, but only before the `MARKER`. So the replace should yield:

```
another thing another thing other text MARKER bla bla something
another thing else another thing MARKER foo bar etc pp something
```

How do I do it in vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example,

```
:%s/something\ze.*MARKER/another thing/g
```

See `:h /\ze`

Comment: Best intro I found: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Regex_lookahead_and_lookbehind

Comment: @matt Would love to do the same with `sed`, do you have the line available?

Comment: @milkpirate https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333417/is-there-an-equivalent-for-vims-zs-in-sed-or-perl

Comment: This is also super useful when you want to insert something: `%s/Insert here:\zs\ze before this/what we wanted to insert/` (note: uses both `\zs` and `\ze`). You essentially replace the "nothing" with your "insert", while guarding the location with the rest of the regex.